# Why are slings damage type only listed as piercing?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, damage-types, ammunition

Why are slings damage type only listed as piercing?

Aren't slings standard ammunition rocks/stones roughly the size of a golf ball which are abundant and should do blugeonig damage? Why not have it list both? Creatively, you can even use glass vails or small glass containers as like alchemist's fire or achit vail as ammounition.

There are historical pictures of spkied stones or metal sling ammo (or a sea urchin if you're that cruel) that can do piercing but it has to be manifactured and rocks/stones are readily available literally every where.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [designer reasoning is off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/14878). If you're asking if there is a mechanical reason then you need to specify that.

Comment: What resource are you looking at that says slings deal piercing damage?

Comment: Sling bullets are much larger than a golf ball - closer to a softball and shaped like a pyramid. They bear about as much resemblance to a toy slingshot stone as a Nerf gun does to a pistol.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to, Dale. Roman sling bullets are sort of almond shaped with a slight point at each end, between one and two inches long (they vary). A pyramid would never fly true, the aerodynamics are all wrong and it would tumble in air.  Here's a collection of sling bullets from around the fall of the Roman Empire: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Roman-lead-sling-bullets-from-the-Late-Iron-Age-fortification-at-Thuin-after-Roymans-et_fig4_279961065

Comment: @DarthPseudonym almond is a much better description for what I was trying to describe

Comment: @DaleM I'm still confused by the 'softball sized' thing. "Thumb sized" is a pretty accurate description of a lead sling bullet (and at that size, might still weigh in at six or eight ounces each).

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 12):

#### [Slings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/sling) deal bludgeoning damage (Weapons Table, PHB, pg. 149):

| Name | Cost | Damage | Weight | Properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sling | 1 sp | ***1d4 bludgeoning*** | - | Ammunition (range 30/120) |